# Браузеры по разному отображают страницы

Tags: css

Решил переделать сайт и начал с [титула](http://www.fxopen.monstrs-inc.com/), но оказалось, что в Мозиле работает все коректно, а в IE криво (как в Опере, не знаю). Я считаю, что дело в CSS, но не знаю где. Кто подскажет, как исправить ситуацию. Спасибо...

P.S. Извините, что дал ссылку. Не знаю, как графику сюда поместить. Вначале планировал другой вопрос задать.

Comment: Почитайте про кроссбраузерность.

Comment: ))))привыкай к этой ситуации)))IE часто так себя ведёт. больше всего проблем с IE6, но его эра уже подходит к концу. про кроссбраузерность тебе уже посоветовали почитать...почитай про хаки.

Comment: А PHP решит эту проблему? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Кроссбраузерность - это единственное, что учит грамотно верстать...

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю. Хотя я решил переделать сайт, что бы перейти на PHP, а для начала все довести до ума в html, а потом смотреть, что можно в блоки заключить, где переменные поставить. Может это решится средствами PHP.

Comment: в пхп или не в пхп а все равно вы от этого хтмл никуда не денетесь))) так что учитесь верстать))) пхп это всего лишь код который исполняется на сервере и высылает то что сделал в браузер.

Answer (score 2):

> Может это решится средствами PHP.

PHP это язык для веб программирования.
ХТМЛ - это якзык разметки, который вместе с КСС, делают разметку, ту которая у вас развалилась. Потому надеяться что ПХП решить проблему верстки - ГЛУПО.

Либо нанимайте профессионального верстальщика, либо в Вашем случае нанимайте профессионального верстальщика. Или возьмите пару уроков по верстке. Что бы не возникало ненужных вопросов.
+ Разберитесь в веб программировании что бы не путать небо с землей, это если хотите в этой сфере работать.

Comment: "Либо нанимайте профессионального верстальщика, либо в Вашем случае нанимайте профессионального верстальщика"  
Эх, безысходность...

Answer (score 0):

С помощью PHP можно реализовать. Так само и на javascript можно. Напишу вам пример как можно реализовать средствами php, чтобы исправить вашу проблему, хоть частично. Только таким методом придется потрать больше время. Самый простой способ сделать для каждого браузера свой css, хоть это "геморой" но всеже для оптимизации само то. Особенно если вы используете технологию CSS3, где начала свойства начинаются с движка браузера (-moz-, -webkit-, -ms-, -o-, т.п).

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Firefox'))
   $browser = 'fir.css';
elseif(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome'))
   $browser = 'chr.css';
elseif(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari'))
   $browser = 'saf.css';
elseif(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera'))
   $browser = 'ope.css';
elseif ( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE'))
   $browser = 'ie.css';
else 
   $browser = 'all.css';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/'.$browser.'" type="text/css" />';
?>
```

При этом не забудьте создать 6 файлов CSS, если Вы будите использовать мой способ. А также исправьте пути к файлам.

Answer (score 0):

Первым дело посети [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru). Полезно будет.

Сверстаешь страницу(с учетом того что не все Браузеры **CSS3** и **HTML5** держат),

сделаешь нормальную разметку,и в **W3Validator** валидируй, не забудь про `DOCTYPE` от него **IE** зависит много чего.

После всего отдельные [хаки](http://dimox.name/personal_css_hacks_for_opera_firefox_ie/) напиши для **IE6-8**(если понадобится).

Answer (score -2):

[[@MonsI](/users/3044/monsi)](/users/3044/monsi) **H**`yperText`**M**`arkup`**L**`anguage` это язык который задает содержимое (описывает контент) **C**`ascadding`**S**`tyle`**S**`heets` задаёт вид этого содержимого (позицию блоков задний фон цвет и так далее) а PHP (даже сами разработчики не знают откуда такое название :) ) это язык который позволяет на сервере обрабатывать информацию и отсылать клиенту документы а это опять таки **HTML** и **CSS**.

> PHP решит эту проблему?

это просто LOL :) 
Чтоб не позориться перед тем, как задавать такие вопросы, прочитайте про HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP etc.

Comment: > PHP (даже сами разработчики не знают откуда такое название :) ) 
orly?

Comment: **Personal Home Page** же :D

######Переименовали конечно знатно...  Hypertext Preprocessor

Comment: дробь Форм Инспектор, спасибо Лердорфу.